# Ionic/How to select multiple item in the listbox?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic 1.3.16 version currently. Here i need to select multiple list items in the below list.

```
<div class="list listbox" ng-if="MemberData.length" ng-repeat="d in MemberData">

        <div class="item  item-avatar item-list-detail item-thumbnail-left thumnail_box">                
                <img ng-if="d.ThumbnailUrl" src="{{d.ThumbnailUrl}}" class="imground">
                <div ng-if="d.ThumbnailUrl==''|| d.ThumbnailUrl==null" class="item-icon-left">
                    <div><i class="icon ion-person bgskyblue  iconx dashboardsquare"></i></div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="spaceWrap"><b>{{d.Name}}</b></h3>
                <p class="spaceWrap">
                    <span class="small"><i class="icon ion-location">&nbsp;</i>{{d.Location}}</span>
                </p>

           </div>
    </div>
```

Screen Shot of the list page:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ng-click` directive:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="clicked(d)" ng-class="{ active: d.selected }">
    <h3 class="spaceWrap"><b>{{d.Name}}</b></h3>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var selected = [];

$scope.clicked = function (member) {
    var index = selected.indexOf(member);
    if(index > -1) {
        selected.splice(index, 1);
        member.selected = false;
    } else {
        selected.push(member);
        member.selected = true;
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/po1cod44/1/)